# Using ALL with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have three tables: Suppliers (id, name...), TypeOfServices(id, service...) and SupplierService(supplierId, ServiceId).

As search input, I have a list with type of service ids. I can have (1) or (1,3) or (1,2,3). I need a query in MySQL that will return to me all the Suppliers that provide the services that are in the search (it can provide other services as well, but it MUST provide the ones that are in the search).

I can't use IN, because IN(2,3) will return the suppliers that have serviceId 2 OR 3, and I need 2 AND 3.

I tried with ALL like this:

```
SELECT * FROM suppliers as s
INNER JOIN supplierservices as ss ON ss.SupplierId = s.Id
WHERE ss.ServiceId = ALL (SELECT id FROM typeofservices WHERE id IN (2, 3))
```

but it's not giving me any results and I have a supplier that provides both services (with id 2 and 3). I think that SQLServer accepts the query like this ALL(2,3), but in MySQL it's not working like that, you have to have a query inside ALL.

Comment: Use IN. You can, and should. Add GROUP BY and HAVING COUNT(*) = n where n is the number of items in the IN()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM suppliers as s
INNER JOIN supplierservices as ss ON ss.SupplierId = s.Id
WHERE ss.ServiceId IN(2,3)
GROUP BY s.id
HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT ServiceId)=2
```

Comment: DISTINCT *shouldn't* be necessary - and points (potentially) to other problems.

Comment: @Strawberry it could return 2 rows both with service id 2 or 3

Comment: The PK on supplierservices should be (id,serviceid). If a surrogate key is used then that should still be maintained as a natural UNIQUE key

Comment: The output is going get confusing if you `SELECT *` and `GROUP BY Suppliers.name` (because of the supplierservices values.) You probably want to `SELECT suppliers.*` with `GROUP BY suppliers.primary_key` if you want to take advantage of MySQL's GROUP BY.

Comment: DISTINCT is not necessary, as you can't have duplicate supplierId and serviceId in the supplierServices table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM suppliers s INNER JOIN
     supplierservices ss
     ON ss.SupplierId = s.Id
GROUP BY s.id
HAVING sum(id = 2) > 0 and
       sum(id = 3) > 0;
```

Just add a new condition to the `having` clause for each value you need.